# How do I implement server-side code for a custom Auth0 login form?

Tags: javascript, json, authentication, server-side

I'm learning to build a simple web app and I'm using Auth0.com to authenticate users for the application. The instructions(https://auth0.com/docs/custom-signup) for creating a sign-up form are pretty simple to me until I make it to the Server Side section at the bottom.

Here's what it says:

> 4. Server Side
>
> After receiving the request from the client, the JSON contained in the
>   body of the message must be enriched with the connection field, that
>   indicates in which connection the user must be stored. POST that JSON
>   to /api/users and in case that succeeds the user is created.
>
> ```
> POST /api/users
> Authorization: Bearer .... access_token ....
>
> {
>      email: "...",        // taken from request
>      password: "...",
>      color: "...",
>      food: "...",
>      connection: "..."      // added by the server
> }
> ```

What does this mean and how do I finish this? If I create another file on my Azure hosting account, what do I call it? Finally, is this all the code I will need? 
Thanks.

Comment: Which underlying technology are you using for your website.
There is a quickstart guide [here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp) for the different languages

Answer (score 0):

```
POST /api/users
Authorization: Bearer .... access_token ....

{
     email: "...",        // taken from request
     password: "...",
     color: "...",
     food: "...",
     connection: "..."      // added by the server
}
```

Above snippet illustrates a sample http request. How to send the request relies on your programming language.

```
POST /api/users                             <- the url and request type
Authorization: Bearer .... access_token .... <- Authorization type to put in the http header

{                                           <- from here is the post data
     email: "...",        // taken from request    
     password: "...",
     color: "...",
     food: "...",
     connection: "..."      // added by the server
}
```

So this is the conception. But if you want the specific code you need to state what language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

as @huazhihao stated, the actual server side implementation depends on the language you use on your server.

if you use javascript, i would recommend looking at the example AuthO is showing on [github](https://github.com/auth0/node-auth0/tree/master/examples/custom-signup).